# Flat extension of local domains

Tags: commutative-algebra, flatness, local-rings, cohen-macaulay, regular-rings

Let $(R,m)$, $(S,n)$ be two local Noetherian domains, $R \subseteq S$ is flat,
and $m \subseteq n$.

**Question 1:**
If $R$ is regular and $S$ is Cohen-Macaulay,
is $S$ also regular?

**Question 2:**
If $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay and $S$ is regular,
is $R$ also regular?

My favorite examples:
$R=k[x(x-1)]_{(x(x-1))}$, $S=k[x]_{(x)}$, $R \subseteq S$ is flat (as a localization of a free extension)
and both local domains are regular (localization of a polynomial ring).

$R=k[x^2,x^3]_{(x^2,x^3)}$, $S=k[x]_{(x)}$, but the extension is not flat.

Notice that $R=k[x^2]_{(x^2)}$, $S=k[x^2,x^3]_{(x^2,x^3)}$ is flat,
$R$ is regular, $S$ is CM, but not regular.

I guess that in some special cases one can apply the miracle flatness theorem.
I do not want to assume that $mS$ is a prime ideal in $S$.
I do not mind to assume that $\dim(R)=\dim(S)$.

Thank you very much!

**Edit:** Perhaps the second answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7432/generalizing-miracle-flatness-matsumura-23-1-via-finite-tor-dimension) question may help. It says:
"If $f: A \to B$ is flat, then obviously the image of any $A$-regular sequence under $f$ is a $B$-regular sequence." (Does it answer Question 1?).

Comment: $S$ regular implies $R$ regular; no need to assume that $R$ is CM.

Comment: @user26857, thank you, this sounds great! (I think that I have seen this result on MO, but could not find it again). Could you please elaborate in an answer?

Comment: It is Theorem 2.2.12 (a) in Bruns and Herzog.

Comment: @user26857, Thank you again. Please, is it possible to replace flatness of $R \subseteq S$ by another condition? What if it is an algebraic ring extension, for example?

Comment: Algebraic ring extensions were not in my target, so I don't know much about these.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help. If you have further ideas concerning the above questions or wish to write an answer-- you are welcome!

Comment: @user26857, please, are there known answers (for both two questions) if we replace 'flat' by 'separable'?

Comment: Theorem 2.2.12 (b) also looks interesting! It is more or less what I was looking for, for question 1.

Comment: For question 1, there are CM $k$-algebras that are not regular, e.g. $k[[t^2, t^3]]$.

Comment: Or your own polynomial example works. The point being that the algebra is free over $k$ (a field) so your hypotheses are trivially satisfied.

Comment: @BadamBaplan, thank you for your comments.